# Restrict browser access to one IP address in httpd.conf for PHP scripts

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, php7

My objective is for *only* IP 1.2.3.4 to be allowed to run the /dir1/hello-php.php script.

'Out-of-the-box' AWS EC2 linux 2 apache 2.4.39 (with only the changes below), PHP 5.7.26, and using Firefox 70.0 64-bit on Windows 10. php.conf also has default settings.

Scripts ..
/dir1/hello-php.php and 
/dir1/hello-html.html

Apache httpd.conf and php.conf have default settings, including ..

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
```

```
<Files ".ht*">
Require all denied
```

Now, I changed httpd.conf with ..

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/dir1">
AllowOverride None
<Files "*.php">
    Require ip 1.2.3.4
</Files>
```

From Firefox ..

https://www.website.com/dir1/hello-php.php gives
"Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /dir1/hello-php.php on this server."
However ..
https://www.website.com/dir1/hello-html.html    works.

Then, if I change the directive to ..

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/dir1">
AllowOverride None
<Files "*.html">
    Require ip 1.2.3.4
</Files>
```

Then ..

https://www.website.com/dir1/hello-php.php  works.
However ..
https://www.website.com/dir1/hello-html.html    gives 
"Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /dir1/hello-html.html on this server."

These results look back to front and don't achieve my objective.

What am I missing in httpd.conf or php.conf in order for *only* IP 1.2.3.4 to be allowed to successfully run the /dir1/hello-php.php script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disallow access to the entire directory and allow it only to the specified IP:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/dir1">
  AllowOverride None
  Require ip 1.2.3.4
```

Or in your example,you could do this

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/dir1">
 AllowOverride None
<Files  ~ "\.(html|php)$">
 Require ip 1.2.3.4
</Files>
```

Also html is not a script

Comment: Thank you, esoroka. That works ;)

Comment: Apachi 2.4.8 - How to put multiple IPs? `Require ip 1.2.3.4` works but `Require ip 1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8` errors in apache restart.